# Sending data frame as table inside email body python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## I have a csv file that i need to  send as a dataframe inside email body.

## However in the output of my email i am unable to see the columns of the csv file and instead it just makes the first row of the csv file as columns.

** Here is my Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

me = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
you = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com'

text = """
Hello, Friend.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html>
<head>
<style> 
  table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body><p>Hello, Friend This data is from a data frame.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""

# with open('input.csv') as input_file:
#     reader = csv.reader(input_file)
#     data = list(reader)

data = pd.read_csv("MySampleFile.csv")
text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "First Attempt"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(me, password)
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: Kindly post the snap of your csv file

Answer (score 7):

## It seems all i had to do was to extract the respective columns inside my csv file into a separate list that could be passed into tabulate method's headers parameter.

*Here is the complete solution*

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

me = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
you = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com'

text = """
Hello, Friend.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body><p>Hello, Friend This data is from a data frame.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""

# with open('input.csv') as input_file:
#     reader = csv.reader(input_file)
#     data = list(reader)

df = pd.read_csv("MySampleFile.csv")
col_list = list(df.columns.values)
data = df
# above line took every col inside csv as list
text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "First Attempt"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(me, password)
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: This is a good one Carl. Worked like a Charm. +1